# What do you call the kind of shooter game in which the background moves on its own?

Tags: terminology, first-person-shooter

On old gaming consoles (first gen) there were games made like FPS, but in which the background moves from right to left, and the scene could stop for some time and then go on. Also, the player could only move the crosshairs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called being on "rails". You can see this in several games, NES Adventures of Bayou Billy stage 2 being one of the oldest I can remember. Revolution X being one of the later ones.
 In levels like this, you are on a "rail" being moved by the screen shooting at things. You don't see the rail and can only control your guns, but feel your movement to the right.

Comment: More specifically, rail shooters

Comment: You sometimes see new games that still do this, mostly in arcades though.

Comment: @Powerlord interesting, could you provide some names if you don't complicate?

Comment: @RS Just google for "rail shooter", plenty of games out there

Comment: Operation Wolf and Time Crisis are good examples of this.